# Event Listener Logic

Tags: javascript

I'll start by saying this is the first post I've made, so please bear with me if I make errors or don't explain things per community standards.

The above said.  I've created a PHP page where I dynamically created a table consisting of items from a MySQL database lookup.  The page, the database lookup, and the presentation is working as I would expect.

My problem is that I've created two columns in the table that I intended to perform EDIT and DELETE actions against the records.  The table has a EDIT and DELETE button for each row (record) of the database in those columns  My code, which works separately from this discussion creates a pop-up form which allows for the action to be taken.

A screenshot of my table is attached: [Screenshot of table and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwfnt.png)

My specific problem is that I don't know if my code below is "legal".  I'm not getting any errors that I can share, but when clicking a button, where I would expect an alert box, I get nothing.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
const allcells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
allcells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('click', () =>
        if (cell.cellIndex == 3) {
            alert("I want to perform an EDIT action here for " + cell.closest('tr').innerText.split("\t")[0])
        if (cell.cellIndex == 2) {
            alert("I want to perform a DELETE action here for " + cell.closest('tr').innerText.split("\t")[0])
    );
    );
});
</script>
```

I thank you in advance for any criticism or guidance you can provide!!!

Comment: "I'm not getting any errors that I can share" - You should see `Uncaught SyntaxError` in your browsers console.

Comment: Thank you @Turnip... I see my mistakes now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several `{}` and `}` missing in your code, a code block that is opened has to be closed again:

```js
const allcells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
allcells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (cell.cellIndex == 3) {
      alert("I want to perform an EDIT action here for " + cell.closest('tr').innerText.split("\t")[0])
    }
    if (cell.cellIndex == 2) {
      alert("I want to perform a DELETE action here for " + cell.closest('tr').innerText.split("\t")[0])
    }
  });
});
```

notice the extra accolades on line 3, 6 and 9
there was also something wrong the closing brackets `)`

Comment: Thank you @stephane-vanraes!  That was it!  I totally messed that one up!  Appreciate the help tremendously!